# Two basic examples of trace diagrams?

Tags: matrices

In the wikipedia entry on Trace Diagrams (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_diagram), the statement is made that "The simplest trace diagrams represent the trace and determinant of a matrix".

Could anyone provide me with the graphic representation of those 2 cases for, say, a 3x3 quadratic matrix with any arbitrary number entries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never heard of trace diagrams. This seems pretty interesting!

Comment: I've also never heard of them, but doesn't it show you those two examples [further down the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_diagram#Diagrams_with_matrices)?

Comment: @Bye_World: I am not sure, since I have found in some pages this proposal for the determinant trace diagram:http://pruffle.mit.edu/3.016-2005/Lecture_25_web/node2.html    At least that is the most common result I get whenn googling, so I am quite confused....

Comment: That's just a stability diagram for ODEs.  I don't think those are the same thing.  But sorry, I've never seen trace diagrams though and I don't have the time or desire to figure them out right now.