# Trace diagrams for tensors, supposed simple Cayley-Hamilton proof

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, notation

Leisurely browsing wikipedia and reading about [trace diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_diagram) I encountered the sentence

> Several results in linear algebra, such as Cramer's Rule and the Cayley–Hamilton theorem, have simple diagrammatic proofs. They are closely related to Penrose's graphical notation.

but I didn't find any references or examples of these. Out of curiosity, how would such a proof look like? Is there a book or resource online for this?

---

A related and also unanswered question can be found at [Two basic examples of trace diagrams?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254640/two-basic-examples-of-trace-diagrams)